# Angularjs modal does not execute a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this modal form where I want the user to select one of three choices.
This selectChain function creates the modal and I have another function that implements the OK, cancel and dismiss actions. So far, it executes everything until the assignSFC() function. I get the proper data and everything...and If I execute assignSFC() function in another place, like using ng-dblclick in a specific element...it is working, so I don't think the problem is in that function.

Do you see anything wrong in the code?

```
$scope.selectChain = function(){

    var modalChain = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'assignSFC.html',
        controller: chainForm,
        resolve: {
            data: function() {
                return $scope.data;
            }
        }

    });

    modalChain.result.then(function(data){
        console.log("modalChain.result.then");
        //console.log("value of chain: "chain)
        console.log("value of data: ",data)
        assignSFC(data);

        console.log("assignSFC was executed")
    });
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the _chainForm_ controller ?

Comment: Probably `assignSFC()` is not available in the scope of your promise. Where is it defined? Try adding `.bind(this)`: `modalChain.result.then(function (data) {...}.bind(this));`